Is it possible to find an ellipse with these conditions?
I am trying to generate an ellipse using two given points in the XY plane. I will call these two points $(x_{start},y_{start})$ and $(x_{end},y_{end})$. The point $(x_{start},y_{start})$ is the terminal point of a segment of line whose initial point is $(x',y')$. This is the segment $L$.
I have tried to find the value of $a$ & $b$ by satisfying the equation $x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1$ using the two points. However, the value of $b^2$ returns as negative when I solve the simultaneous system of equations. I think they should be always be positive. I thought that this approach would give a straightforward answer but I am not sure why the values are negative. Does this mean that the points cannot lie on the same ellipse ?
I have also generated this information through derivations:

Considered $L$ as the tangent to the point $(x_{start},y_{start})$ on the ellipse( which I am
assuming it exists). Then, I calculated the equation of line $l_1$,
which is normal to $L$ at $(x_{start},y_{start})$.
If the point $(x_{end},y_{end})$ is considered as a vertex of any of the major or minor axis of the ellipse, this straight line will be represented by $l_2:y = y_{end}$.
The intersection of the lines $l_1$ and $l_2$ can also be calculated easily. This intersection is represented by the coordinates $(x_{int},y_{int})$

Can I use this information to find an equation of ellipse ?
EDIT - I have attached here a diagram of the problem.

how can $b$ be forced to be negative since its only intervention is through $b^2$, which means that both $b$ and $-b$ are adequate?

This is what I am confused about. Maybe it's the notation. In textbooks, it is usually referred to as $-b$ and $b$ as two ends of the minor axis. So, for my case, the value of $b$ would be just the real portion of the calculation ?

actually, I don't understand the question; 2 points aren't enough to define an ellipse uniquely; from what I've seen with a few google searches, one requires 5 points to achieve that. You do not explain the role of $(x',y')$ either. Can you refine your problem statement?

Did you mean "the value of $^2$ returns as negative"?

Do you also request line $L$ to be tangent to the ellipse, or not?

Yes. Apologies the value of $b^2$ is returned negative and $L$ should be tangent to ellipse.

Again: are you looking only for an ellipse whose axes are parallel to coordinate axes, or also for a rotated ellipse?

Yes, any of the axes of the ellipse should be parallel to the X axis. This axes of the ellipse should pass through $(x_{end},y_{end})$.

It would help a lot if you could provide a diagram.

If the equation of the ellipse must be in the form $x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1$ then the center of the ellipse must be at the origin. There is then often not an ellipse satisfying your other constraints. For example, if $(x_{start},y_{start})$ is in the first quadrant then the slope of $L$ must be negative or there is no ellipse; and if the slope is negative then the ellipse is determined by $L$ and only points on that ellipse can be $(x_{end},y_{end})$.

Thanks for the info David but it's not compulsory that the ellipse must be in the origin-centered form. I think the only two conditions that I need to satisfy are that the ellipse should start from $(x_{start},y_{end}$ with sufficient tangency and end at $(x_{end},y_{end}$.

I also edited the question and added a diagram.

The equation of the ellipse can be written as:
$$
{(x-x_0)^2\over a^2}+{(y-y_{end})^2\over b^2}=1.
$$
Substitute here the coordinates of $(x_{start},y_{start})$ and $(x_{end},y_{end})$, and add the condition of tangency ($y'=\ $slope of $L$ at $(x_{start},y_{start})$) to find the unknowns $a$, $b$ and $x_0$.

You assume the axes of the ellipse are horizontal and vertical?

@GEdgar So said the OP in a comment.

Thanks I was able to solve the problem numerically by solving three equations for three unknowns using slope specification. Analytically, it gets messy really fast.

I have use Geogebra for doing such a thing: I have created two points, $A$ and $B$, and from that, I have derived two new points, $C$ and $D$, making a simple rectangle like that ($x_C=x_A$, $y_C=y_B$ and $x_D=x_B$ and $y_D=y_A$).
Geogebra has the feature to create a conic section, based on five points, so I started with the four existing points and created a fifth point along, it gave me the following result:

So, creating an ellipse from two points does not look that complicated :-)
